# How to only run HttpModule methods for ASP.NET pages

Tags: asp.net, httpmodule

I realize HttpModules will run for all requests. I would like a method within my HttpModule to run for only ASPX pages.

ASP.NET 4.6, IIS 8.5

- There is no file extension in the `Request.URL` or `Request.RawUrl`
- The `Request.ContentType` is empty when I step through for debugging
- I cannot currently find anything within any of the other `Request` properties that tell me the type at this stage of the Request

Relevant code section

```
public void Init(HttpApplication context)
{
    context.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(OnBeginRequest);
}

public void OnBeginRequest(Object source, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication)source;
    /*
     * Here is where I'd like to filter 
     *   e.g., if (IsAspxPage()) { DoSomething(); }
     * app.Context.Request.ContentType is ""
     * app.Context.Request.Url has no file extension for any files at this stage of the request
     */
}
```

Is this simply not possible in the BeginRequest event handler? If not, what's the earliest event to use where it would be?